# Can't solve this? How would you fix this? "Variable binding in a condition requires an initializer" and "Expected '{' after 'if' condition"

Tags: swift

The title summarized my problem. I'm new to coding and I don't understand how to solve the problem.

I've tried pretty much all I know.

```
import UIKit
import AVKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var PowerLVLlabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    }

    @IBAction func randomNumber(_ sender: Any) {

        let randomNumber = Int.random(in: 1000...10000)
        PowerLVLlabel.text = String(randomNumber)
        if case { randomNumber; >=9000 == (true);
            func playVideo() {
                guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "over 9000", ofType:"mp4") else {
                    debugPrint("over 9000.mp4 not found")
                    return
                }
                {let player = AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))
                let playerController = AVPlayerViewController()
                playerController.player = player
                    present(playerController, animated: true) }
                    {player.play()
}
```

Comment: start var names `PowerLVLlabel`  with small letter `powerLVLlabel`

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
func playVideo(){
    guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "over 9000", ofType:"mp4") else {
        debugPrint("over 9000.mp4 not found")
        return
    }
    let player = AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))
    let playerController = AVPlayerViewController()
    playerController.player = player
    present(playerController, animated: true)
    player.play()

}

@IBAction func randomNumber(_ sender: Any) {

        let randomNumber = Int.random(in: 1000...10000)
        PowerLVLlabel.text = String(randomNumber)

        if randomNumber >= 9000{
            playVideo()
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Sh_Khan thanks for the information. Will keep that in mind. though I just only cleared the code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get `playVideo` function out of `randomNumber` and remove some un needed `;` and `{}`

```
import UIKit
import AVKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var powerLVLlabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    }

    func playVideo() {
        guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "over 9000", ofType:"mp4") else {
            debugPrint("over 9000.mp4 not found")
            return
        }
        let player = AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))
        let playerController = AVPlayerViewController()
        playerController.player = player
        present(playerController, animated: true)
        player.play()

    }

    @IBAction func randomNumber(_ sender: Any) {

        let randomNumber = Int.random(in: 1000...10000)
        powerLVLlabel.text = String(randomNumber)
        if randomNumber >= 9000 {
            playVideo()
        }

    }
}
```